# Repo name size limitation when trying to Create Docker Automated Build

Tags: github, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, dockerhub

While trying to link a public github repo to an automated build on the Docker hub, I'm experiencing the behavior whereby clicking create button on the page causing no visible response at all.  I looked into it and found the following javascript errors in Chrome dev tools:

[image]

[image]

Is this a documented behavior or a bug in the way Docker Hub's 'Create Automated Build' functionality works that one cannot exceed a certain number of characters.  It says 50, however the length of the repo's name is less than that as far as I can count: `docker-orchestration-and-microservices-course`.  If that's a feature, how's the name calculated and where is this limitation documented?

Thanks.